# I'm told to down load a text file from another website and to put in the root directory of my website

Tags: download

I want to know how to down load a text file from another website and how to put it in the root directory of my website.Can you help me with problem please.THANK'S !!

Answer (score 1):

As a program, or as a human action?

As a human, you should be able to take the link and download the file, upload to your website using for example FTP or (hopefully no one does this now) frontpage.

If you mean programattically, well its almost the same. Your script would need to open the file in the root directory, open the URL and read in the data sent and save it to the file, close the file. However, how to do so exactly depends on the lanugage you want, is this a repeated event or a once off?

Comment: You can "right click" and download that, or as mentioned above, programattically do the same

Answer (score 1):

This type of request usually happens when you are requesting a service that requires proof that you are the website owner. Being the owner of that website would also indicate that you should have at least ftp access over your site. If you are hosting the website yourself, this is an easy task you just copy the file into the root directory (windows default is c:\inetpub\wwwroot, ubuntu default is /var/www/). However if your website is hosted, you need to find your ftp username and password and utilize an ftp program like FileZilla. If you want to tell us what file host you use maybe someone can give you exact instructions. But beware of what file you host.

Comment: It looks like this is hosted on godaddy.  If thats true here is a link to the instructions for using ftp on godaddy. I think the root folder is "/" for godaddy when going through ftp for your site. http://www.godaddy.com/Popups/ftp.aspx. Are you saying that you have copied the file there already? Or that is the address of the file you expect?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the URL of the text file you can put it into your browser and then save the file to your disk.  You then need to FTP it to your web server (or whatever method you normally use to get files onto the server)

Answer (score 0):

In PHP:

```
<?php
$resource = curl_init('http://www.someserver.com/file.txt');
// important, otherwise curl_exec will output directly
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
$data = curl_exec($resource);
curl_close($resource);
file_put_contents('/dir/localfile.txt', $data);
```

Or even better, with a bash script with a simple wget and cp.